# Better way to replace a set of signs with strings

Tags: java

I need to make a simple code, which get a `string`, and an `array of String`, and  replace the `?` signs with each element of array.

Here is the test case in junit:

```
@Test
    public void QueryFitterTest() {

        ArrayList<String> args=new ArrayList<String>(); 

        args.add("Bad code");
        args.add("The code is buggy");

        String res = QueryMaker.queryFitter("insert into  vulnerability (name,descirption) values(?,?)",args);
        String correctQuery="insert into  vulnerability (name,descirption) values(Bad code,The code is buggy)";
        assertEquals(correctQuery, res);

    }
```

and here is the  code:

```
public static String queryFitter(String query, ArrayList<String> args){

    String[] colapsedQuery = query.split("");
    int parmNum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<colapsedQuery.length;i++){
        if(colapsedQuery[i]=="?"){
            colapsedQuery[i]=args.get(parmNum);
            parmNum++;
        }

    }

    query=concatenator(colapsedQuery);
    return query;

}
public static String concatenator(String[] colapsedQuery){
    String delimiter = "";
    String result = String.join(delimiter, colapsedQuery);
    System.out.println("query is: "+result);
    return result;
}
```

The code is working fine but

I don't like my approach, is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: tl;dr on the dup: `colapsedQuery[i]=="?"` will *never* be true.

Comment: `colapsedQuery[i]=="?"`. Use a char `'?'` and just use `String.charAt(n)`

Comment: If this is going against SQL, the "better" way, IMO, would be to use a PreparedStatement. What is going to happen if there are special characters in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are 2 issues:
>
> 1- My code cannot pass the test, it returns the query without any
>   change.
>
> query is: insert into  vulnerability (name,descirption) values(?,?)
>
> 2-
>   I don't like my approach, is there an easier way to do it?

Well, the good news is that your `JUnit` test discovered a bug in your program. The other good news is that the answer to both of your questions is the same. Just fix your code in the method `queryFitter`.

Try the following code:

```
public static String queryFitter(String query, ArrayList<String> args){

   for(int i=0;i<args.size();i++){
      query = query.replaceFirst("\\?",args.get(i));
   } 

   return query;
}
```

Almost forgot to tell you. You don't need `concatenator` method either.

Comment: Awsome, thanks man